# What IDE or text editor can I use for solidity in ethereum?

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development

I need to know how to use solidity (What IDE to use) and is there any other languages that is used in the Ethereum blockchain.

Comment: If you just want an IDE in the browser for quick experimentation, you can use https://ethfiddle.com/

Comment: You can also use Web IDE's such as Remix https://remix.ethereum.org/ or Superblocks Lab https://lab.superblocks.com/. Great for learning, quick iterations, and experimentation 

There are however no fully-fledged downloadable IDE's specifically made for Ethereum. There are some plug-ins for traditional IDE's, but if you want to go down that route you might as well try the Truffle Framework.

Answer (score 3):

you will find in the official documentation a list of the tools used for solidity, please read https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

for the other languages there is Serpent and LLL but solidity is the more popular.